# How to get the list of columns in a Django Queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a code that creates multiple complicated querysets from different tables, using lots of annotations, etc...

The code is then joining those querysets using union.

Each of those querysets by itself seems to be fine. Calling `print(len(qset))` works for each of them.

But after `combined_qset = qset1.union(qset2)`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: each UNION query must have the
same number of columns
LINE 1: ..., '') AS "owner" FROM "t1") UNION (SELECT "field_x...
                                                     ^
```

When I look at the code, I count the number of fields in `.only(...)` and `.values(...)` calls, count the numbers of annotations, etc, it seems that all those querysets have exactly the same number of columns.

The error message shows just a tiny little part of the SQL generated (see above), so it's not really helpful.

Is there a simple way to get the list of columns of a queryset, so I can find the discrepancy and fix it?

Comment: It's really hard to tell anything without seeing the code you have. It'd be much easier if you shared the code.

Comment: The code is long and includes many tables. The important part of the code is `combined_qset = qset1.union(qset2)`, which causes the `each UNION query must have the
same number of columns`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it!

```
print('qset1:', len(qset1), qset1[0].__dict__.keys())
print('qset2:', len(qset2), qset2[0].__dict__.keys())
print('qset3:', len(qset2), qset3[0].__dict__.keys())
...
```

`qset[0]` gives the first row of the queryset `qset` (This only work if the queryset has at least one row)

`.__dict__` converts that row to a dictionary - a dictionary with keys being column names and values are the row elements

`.keys()` gives the list of keys of the dictionary, thus, the columns

This prints the list of the columns for all the querysets.

Comment: It has to be noted, that `.__dict__` also has other class atributes of the QuerySet, e.g. `_state`